# Any random password results in successful login on tty

Tags: security, freebsd, password, root

I can login to my machine (FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE) for any user (for example: `root` or `operator` or any that exists in `/etc/passwd`) with any random password that I type...

I tried to reset password for `root` with `passwd`, but again if I try to login I can login with any random password that I type in... strange.

This ONLY works when I login directly from `tty`. When trying to log in via SSH, everything is as it should be - I need to give correct password to log in. How to fix this?

EDIT: Contents of `/etc/ttys`:

```
# name  getty                           type    status          comments
#
# If console is marked "insecure", then init will ask for the root password
# when going to single-user mode.
console none                            unknown off secure
#

console none                            unknown off secure
#
ttyv0   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
# Virtual terminals
ttyv1   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv2   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv3   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv4   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv5   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv6   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv7   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"         xterm   on  secure
ttyv8   "/usr/local/bin/xdm -nodaemon"  xterm   off secure
# Serial terminals
# The 'dialup' keyword identifies dialin lines to login, fingerd etc.
ttyu0   "/usr/libexec/getty std.9600"   dialup  off secure
ttyu1   "/usr/libexec/getty std.9600"   dialup  off secure
ttyu2   "/usr/libexec/getty std.9600"   dialup  off secure
ttyu3   "/usr/libexec/getty std.9600"   dialup  off secure
# Dumb console
dcons   "/usr/libexec/getty std.9600"   vt100   off secure
```

Comment: Check your `/etc/inittab`, what are the lines for e.g. tty1?

Comment: Sorry, but there is no `/etc/inittab`.

Comment: I missed the freebsd hint. Is there something in /etc/ttys?

Comment: Sorry, I also didn't know what equivalent of inittab for FreeBSD is. Here you go: http://ideone.com/PV6DJg

Comment: The file looks normal. What's in `/etc/login.conf`? I hope noone replaced your original `/bin/login` by a script or something selfmade.

Comment: `/etc/login.conf`: http://ideone.com/9gKu0x and there is no `/bin/login` at all.

Comment: One more try: are there any guest entries in `/etc/pam.conf`. That would explain that any password is accepted.

Comment: Compare the auth lines /etc/pam.d/login and /etc/pam.d/system to /etc/pam.d/sshd also it is /usr/bin/login not /bin/login

Comment: To make sure your `/usr/bin/login` is correct you can run `sha256 -c 70249bc89ed1aa25208ee373484974c5e2cb9e86a1774f6fb7a3e0426257fb80 $(which login)`

Comment: @Craig: Thank you! In `/etc/pam.d/system` there was a line `auth sufficient pam_unix.so no_warn try_first_pass nullok` and change to `auth required pam_unix.so no_warn try_first_pass nullok` (from `sufficient` to `required`) helped. Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: You should post the result of this discussion as answer.

Comment: The problem isn't solved to the end. After this change certain users can't do `sudo tcsh` (they don't do `sudo su` as `root` account is locked with `pw lock root`). When I get back to `auth sufficient pam_unix.so no_warn try_first_pass nullok` in `/etc/pam.d/system` - they can do `sudo tcsh` but I can login on `tty` with any password that I type for user `root`. A hint: when I tried to change password for this user with `passwd joe` I'm getting this kind of error: `passwd: Sorry, 'passwd' can only change passwords for local or NIS users.`. I'm a little bit confused now.

Comment: This problem occurs only on machines where LDAP is configured. Like here: https://wiki.freebsd.org/LDAP

Comment: @MarkZakred. Please put this detail about ldap on the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Edit /etc/ttys so that the line:

```
console none                            unknown off secure
```

is replaced with:

```
console none                            unknown off insecure
```

Also, you should have only one console line in your config.